# apache solr 5.3 on windows, how to change the time zone in logs?

Tags: solr, solr5

in the logs, timestamp is a couple hours ahead of my timezone, which is PST. How to change it to the correct timezone, or make it get the system time whichever way available ?
I am using Solr 5.3 on windows
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

its the log4j config under resourrces folder.
Change:
org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout to org.apache.log4j.EnhancedPatternLayout 
and now can change the time zone from %d to something like %d{ISO8601}{GMT-7}